# file upload & swf conversion tool - similar to slideshare

Tags: file-upload, flash

I'm looking for a tool or service to enable a user to upload single, standard file formats (ex. `ppt`, `pdf`, `doc`, `flv`, `mov`) and convert to `swf` through my website - similar to what slideshare does. Any suggestions? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The better alternative is using service [AuthorSTREAM](http://www.authorstream.com/).

I check out several services and the only one is this.

This SaaS convert to swf, mp4 (video) and other formats.

I'll change for this because Slideshare PHP API upload slideshow method stopped last 2 weeks without reason.